# Do Media Foundation Transforms have to have files as their input sources?

Tags: video, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I need to be able to take in multiple consecutive YUV frames, and encode them into a H264 video stream.

Do you know if Media Foundation Transforms (MFTs) can accomplish this?

Seems like all the examples I'm finding online using MFTs are take one video file as an input, convert it, and save it as a separate file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[H.264 Video Encoder MFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can do it. It's input is a sequence of raw/uncompressed video frames (with data in memory), properly formatted. MFT operation is unrelated to files. Its output is bitstream as byte buffer.